# Pesquisar em várias tabelas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte SQL

```
SELECT * FROM 
cliente as c 
INNER JOIN cliente_contato as ct ON ct.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR ct.telefone LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
JOIN cliente_ip as cip ON cip.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
INNER JOIN cliente_mac as mac ON mac.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
INNER JOIN cliente_pppoe as pppoe ON pppoe.usuario LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
WHERE c.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
```

Gostaria de pesquisar em várias tabela a mesma TAG, se tiver, retorna o results... Mas ali retorna sempre zero... O que será? Alguém me ajuda?

## Estrutura da Tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A pesquisa é `OR` ou `AND`?

Comment: A pesquisa é OR, se tiver dentro da tabela, qualquer uma delas.. retorna, se não retorna vazio... mas o campo de pesquisa é um só.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analisando sua `SQL` da pra ver que não ficou muito claro pra você como fazer os relacionamentos nos `JOINS`, recomendo que leia aqui: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448)

Partindo para seu problema, eu faria algo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM cliente as c 
INNER JOIN cliente_contato as ct ON ct.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN cliente_ip as cip ON cip.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN cliente_mac as mac ON mac.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN cliente_pppoe as pppoe ON pppoe.id_cliente = c.id
```

Dessa forma está vinculada todas tabelas pelo seu `id_cliente` garantindo a integridade dos dados, caso alguma dessas tabelas não seja obrigatório no seu resultado você pode trocar `INNER` por `LEFT`.

Partindo para sua pesquisa:

```
WHERE ct.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' 
   OR ct.telefone LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR cip.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR mac.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR pppoe.usuario LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR c.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
```

Dessa forma ele vai trazer o resultado se apenas **uma** das condições atender.

#### Código Final

```
SELECT * FROM cliente as c 
INNER JOIN cliente_contato as ct ON ct.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN cliente_ip as cip ON cip.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN cliente_mac as mac ON mac.id_cliente = c.id
INNER JOIN cliente_pppoe as pppoe ON pppoe.id_cliente = c.id
WHERE ct.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' 
   OR ct.telefone LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR cip.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR mac.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR pppoe.usuario LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
   OR c.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
```

Comment: Apenas troquei o id_cliente por id, que é o correto e também ao invés de usar INNER, troquei por LEFT. Deu certo! Agradeço pessoal.

Comment: De fato, corrigido.

Answer (score 1):

> Com o uso do inner join se uma das tabelas não tiver o resultado ele não vai retornar linha alguma. Tente com o LEFT JOIN.

Nos inners join vc tem que usar a condição on para determinar quando vai haver a junção, no caso eu coloquei que cada tabela possui o id_cliente ai eu faço a junção com o cliente usando o id e seus LIKE eu coloco na condição WHERE

```
SELECT * FROM 
cliente as c 
LEFT JOIN cliente_contato as ct ON ct.id_cliente = c.id
LEFT JOIN cliente_ip as cip ON cip.id_cliente = c.id
LEFT JOIN cliente_mac as mac ON mac.id_cliente = c.id
LEFT JOIN cliente_pppoe as pppoe ON pppoe.id_cliente = c.id
WHERE c.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR ct.nome LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR ct.telefone LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR cip.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR mac.detalhes LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%' OR pppoe.usuario LIKE '%{$pesquisa}%'
```

O correto seria você fazer queries diferentes e fazer execuções diferentes!

Comment: Também não deu certo, por conta da tag de pesquisa... Preciso elaborar o SQL que se encontrar algum resultado dentre as tabelas, retorne, independentemente de qual tabela tenha sido.

Comment: Mas oque é esse resultado? é um count? é uma lista de colunas com varias linhas..., não estou entendendo sua lógica

Comment: entendi agora, só um minuto

Comment: Pronto agora deve funcionar

Comment: deu certo... usei o exemplo do Maico, agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Eu vi agora a resposta dele :) é exatamente aquilo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria desta forma:

```
SELECT c.*, ct.*, cip.*, mac.*, pppoe.* 
FROM cliente c 
LEFT JOIN cliente_contato ct ON (ct.id_cliente=c.id)
LEFT JOIN cliente_ip cip ON (cip.id_cliente=cip.id)
LEFT JOIN cliente_mac mac ON (mac.id_cliente=cip.id)
LEFT JOIN cliente_pppoe pppoe ON (pppoe.id_cliente=cip.id)
WHERE c.nome LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
OR    ct.nome LIKE '%$pesquisa%' 
OR    ct.telefone LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
OR    cip.detalhes LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
OR    mac.detalhes LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
OR    pppoe.usuario LIKE '%$pesquisa%';
```